# Retrieving data SQL less decimals than stored

Tags: sql, pdo, database-connection, decimal

In my database I have the stored value:

```
quant = 1335.326233552119
```

But when I use PDO_MYSQL to retrieve this (`select quant from table`, etc) the returned value is:

```
  quant = 1335.3262335521
```

How can I get the whole stored value?

**UPDATE**:

When this field (`quant`) was created it was chosen 'double' as type, but no size was defined.  (maybe this information is important)

```
  $db_name = 'databasename';

  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=$db_name", $user, $password);  
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $consulta = $pdo->prepare('select quant from table where (x=?) and (y=?)'); 
  $consulta->execute(array($x,$y));

  $result = $consulta->fetchObject()
  var_dump($result->quant);    //1335.3262335521
```

Comment: So if you run your query on the database itself you get the correct number?

Comment: @JChao Exactly, when I run the queries on PHPMyAdmin I see that the correct value is stored.

Comment: which datatype did you use in your database?

Comment: @northkildonan This field is a double.

Comment: i got no problems with `PDO` when i use the datatype `double(16,12) UNSIGNED`. maybe you could show more of your code - so also the `PHP/PDO` part?

Comment: @northkildonan I thought it was a simple issue, like an attibute of PDO, that is why I didn't add code before. But there it is.

Comment: what happens if you try `echo $consulta->fetchColumn();` (updated!)

Comment: and afaik it's always better to use the `decimal` datatype for exact values in `MySQL` ` since both, `PHP` and `MySQL` tend to automatically round `float` or  `double` datatype values.

Comment: @northkildonan Doing exactly as you said, thre was an error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Comment: well, i am sorry - this seems to be a deeper problem than expected.

Comment: @northkildonan Well, my last answer was the response to "echo $consulta", if I try "echo $consulta->fetchColumn();", the result is "1335.3262335521" as before. =/ [thanks for the decimal tip, btw]

Comment: @carla one last guess: `echo number_format($consulta->fetchColumn(), 12);`  - to maybe force `PHP` to show 12 numbers after the decimal point.

Comment: @carla - strange, but cool that it worked this way. i'll post it as an answer now if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after failing to reproduce the error on my own webserver the solution was to force PHP to put out more numbers after the period with `number_format`:

```
echo number_format($consulta->fetchColumn(), 12);
```

this might have to do something with the setup and configuration of `PHP`.
if i should find out more about it, i will add it here.